# Creación de un trigger para auditoría

Tags: trigger, insert, update

necesito ayuda con este trigger que su objetivo sería guardar una auditoría de los datos de la tabla paises, donde quisiera guardar en el formato NombreColumna:-:Valor::-::NombreColumna:-:Valor, de todas las columnas que su
DATA_TYPE sea ('INT', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR').

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia la agradecería, estoy tratando de hacer el insert primero, la sería para las tres accciones, en el update solo guardaría las columnas que fueron modificadas, no todas.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Audit_Paises ON dbo.Paises
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @SysUser    varchar(100)
    DECLARE @FullName   varchar(250)
    DECLARE @TableName  varchar(250)
    DECLARE @Action     varchar(50) 
    DECLARE @OldValue   varchar(Max)
    DECLARE @NewValue   varchar(Max)
    DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME AS varchar(100)
    DECLARE @DATA_TYPE AS varchar(100)
    DECLARE @SQLTEXT AS nvarchar(Max)
    DECLARE @SEPARATOR AS VARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @SEPARATORCOLUMN AS VARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @COLUMN_VALUE AS nvarchar(Max)
    DECLARE @DATAFULLTEXT AS NVARCHAR(Max) 

SET @TableName = 'Paises';

DECLARE ColumnInfo CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='paises' AND DATA_TYPE IN ('INT', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR') ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
SET @SQLTEXT = ''
SET @SEPARATOR = ':::'
SET @SEPARATORCOLUMN = '::::'
SET @DATAFULLTEXT = ''

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Deleted )
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Inserted )
            BEGIN
                --UPDATE
                SET @OldValue = ''
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                --DELETE
                SET @OldValue = ''
            END  
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        --INSERT
        SELECT @SysUser = I.LastUserUpdate FROM Inserted I;
        IF @SysUser <> '' 
            BEGIN
                SELECT @FullName = FullName FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserName = @SysUser    
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT  @SysUser = login_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
                SET @FullName = 'Admin for console' 
            END

        OPEN ColumnInfo
        FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnInfo INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE
        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLTEXT = 'DECLARE @SEPARATOR AS VARCHAR(5);';
            SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'DECLARE @SEPARATORCOLUMN AS VARCHAR(5);';
            SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'DECLARE @COLUMN_VALUE AS nvarchar(Max);';
            SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'DECLARE @DATAFULLTEXT AS NVARCHAR(Max);';

            SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'SET @SEPARATOR = '':-:'';';  
            SET @SQLTEXT = @SQLTEXT + 'SET @SEPARATORCOLUMN = ''::-::'';';
            
            SET @SQLTEXT = CONCAT(@SQLTEXT, N'SELECT @COLUMN_VALUE = Coalesce(CAST( ', @COLUMN_NAME, ' AS VARCHAR(Max)), '''') FROM ', 'paises ', ' WHERE id = 1 ;');
            SET @SQLTEXT = CONCAT(@SQLTEXT, N' SET @DATAFULLTEXT = @DATAFULLTEXT + @SEPARATORCOLUMN +''', @COLUMN_NAME,''' + @SEPARATOR + @COLUMN_VALUE;');

            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLTEXT;
            
            FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnInfo INTO @COLUMN_NAME, @DATA_TYPE
        END
        CLOSE ColumnInfo
        DEALLOCATE ColumnInfo

        INSERT  INTO dbo.AuditLogs ( SysUser, FullName, TableName, Action, OldValue, NewValue)
                SELECT  @SysUser, @FullName, @TableName, 'INSERT', '', @DATAFULLTEXT FROM Inserted
    END
GO
```

Gracias de antemano.